# Grab an object out of objects base on specific field value

Tags: javascript

In my AngularJS

this.device return `15` objects. Each object contain a `dataType` field and it has diff values on all 15 of them. I would like to grab/access only if `dataType == "PROTOCOL"` I would do something like this if I have access to **underscore.js**, but in this project, I don't have it.

```
this.device.protocol = _.find(this.device, {dataType: "PROTOCOL"});
```

What is JS way to access this without having to do a for-loop?

Comment: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore#_find

Comment: Wow. Love the GitHub link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned.

```
this.device.protocol = this.device.find(x => x.dataType === "PROTOCOL");
```

Comment: cleaner, I like this find()

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and check against your desired property.

```
this.device.protocol = this.device.filter(({dataType}) => dataType == "PROTOCOL")[0];
```

Comment: It returns an array, so you need to add [0] to end of the line

Comment: I added it. Thanks for pointing my omission out, @Helix.